# How can I override just one property of a controltemplate?

Tags: xaml, listview, microsoft-metro, controltemplate

I'm trying to override the padding property of a ListViewItemPresenter in Windows Store apps.
Everything works when I copy the complete generic ListView style, change the padding and apply that style as ItemContainerStyle to my ListView.

Now I need to do this for another ListView. How can I override just one property of the ListViewItemPresenter ControlTemplate without copying the complete style all over again?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found came from the link below.  I copy-pasted the answer below.

The idea is to copy the full Windows 10 style into your dictionary and give it a key.  You don't need to modify the style and you only have to copy it once.  (Though once more than ideally you should have to.)  Since it now has a key, you can create another style "BasedOn" that key and modify it.

[https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d3c1f120-b11f-4d14-b45c-7bdf3e9233be/inheriting-a-default-application-style-xaml?forum=winappswithcsharp][1]

First, create the default style for the control in your App.xaml-level resource dictionary, but give it an x:Key

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonDefaultStyle" TargetType="Button">
    ...
</Style>
```

Then, create another style that inherits from this style.

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultStyle}" />

</Style>
```

Default styles can be found here
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299122.aspx]
or on your computer at a location like
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10586.0\Generic\generic.xaml